# Scheme (Racket) Properly written function not working with some inputs

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket, infinite-loop

So I have written I function in racket that calculates Sums:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) next b))))
```

Term is what function is applied to every argument. A is the beginning next is how we advance to the next element (i.e. a2 = 2*a1 or a2 = a1 +1 etc.) and b is the final element.

There are 2 additional functions:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
```

If I  type:

> (sum square 1 inc 5)
>   I get which is correct 55

But if I type:

> (sum square 1 square 5)

I am stuck in a loop!? Why is that a2 should be a1*a1 and a3=a2*a2 and a should surpass b so the condition to end the recursion would be fultifield. Very strange.

Comment: (square 1) will never be greater than 5 as it is always 1 :-)

Comment: I feel so dumb now! Thank you!

Comment: @DiegoNietoCid: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Svante I felt it was to short for an answer...should I still move it into a proper answer?

Comment: @Svante Ok, I made it an answer after reading some questions on meta regarding short answers. Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer if you think it is ok Mitaka.

Comment: I am new here accepted it now ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `sum` function will loop forever because `(square 1)` always evaluates to `1` and will never be greater than `5`.